# Redmine authentification by url

Tags: httprequest, redmine, redmine-api

Basic HTTP GET request work by just calling url in browser . Is possible to authenticate  a user somehow calling an url , that include his login and password ??

Comment: You want to pass the user's username and password in the url querystring? You know that's horribly insecure, right?

Comment: I got a system based on asp.net , inside the system i got an iframe,that is the redmine , and got task to authentificate if user logged on main asp,net project , thats the only solution i got at the moment , if got other ideas ill be glad to hear them :)